# Replace or add a string to a file

Tags: sed, text-processing

I know sed can replace a piece of string within a text file like this :

```
sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' test.txt
```

But, how do I replace the line if it exists and automatically add it on a new line if it doesn't exist?

Thanks.

Edit : Thank you for your responses. As per the requests on your comments and answer, here's more details :

- I want to check the existence of the old string and replace it with the new string if it exists.
- I want to add the new string in a new line at the end of the txt file if the old string does not exist
- If there are multiple occurances of the same string, it would be an error since its a config file.The other occurances can be removed after replacing the first occurance.

Comment: Add it in a new line where? At the end of the doc?

Comment: Check existence of old or new string or both? Add old or new string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to do this it to bring `grep` into the equation. First check whether the file contains the string with a quick `grep` and then append or substitute accordingly:

```
grep -q string file && 
    sed -i 's/string/newstring/' file || echo "newstring" >> file
```

The above is a shorthand way of writing:

```
if grep -q string file; then 
    sed -i 's/string/newstring/' file
else
    echo "newstring" >> file
fi
```

Personally, however, I would use `perl` for this instead. Just read the file once and set a variable to 1 if the substitution was made. Then, at the end, add the string if the variable is not 1:

```
perl -lpe '$i=1 if s/oldstring/newstring/; 
           END{print "newstring" if $i!=1;}' file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

Comment: @kos yes, the `END{}` is executed after the file has been closed so it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the nice shorthand, but wouldn't it be better to use `printf "\nnewstring"` as `echo "newstring"` seems to append it to the last (non-empty) line? On the other hand, using `printf "\n..."` leaves an empty line above when there's already an empty line at the end. Any better solution for this?

Comment: @Sadi no, `echo foo >> file` will add `foo` in a new line. So will `printf 'foo\n' >> file`.

Comment: I also thought so but when I tested on this occasion in a new text file ending with a non-empty line (i.e. no empty line at the end of the file) the command `echo foo >> file` always appended "foo" to that last non-empty line and added an empty line after that, so it's apparently inserting "foo\n" instead of "\nfoo" then (Ubuntu 15.10). I'll further check this issue...

Comment: @Sadi that's different. The `>>` operator appends to the end of the file. Normally, the last character of a text file is `\n` so it will append the text after the `\n` and make a new line. If you know your file doesn't end with a `\n`, you would have to use `printf '\nfoo\n' >> file`, yes. If you need to deal with such cases, please edit your question and make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

This should achieve what is required:

```
grep -q "oldstring" test.txt
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "newstring" >> test.txt
else
    sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' test.txt
fi
```

Comment: @kos : Thank you for the UUOC award ( : - D ) and for taking the time to teach something to this beginner in shell scripting. I'll now try to improve the code above.

Comment: I didn't really mean to "award" it to you, just to point that out. :D. Looks better, you could also shorten the `if / else` check to this single line: `[ $? -eq 1 ] && echo "newstring" >> test.txt || sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' test.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Using AWK:

```
<<<"$(<in)" awk '{if(/foo/){x=sub(/foo/, "bar", $0)};print}END{if(x!=1){print "bar"}}' >in
```

```
% cat in1
string oldstring string
% cat in2
string foo string
% <<<"$(<in1)" awk '{if(/oldstring/){x=sub(/oldstring/, "newstring", $0)};print}END{if(x!=1){print "newstring"}}' >in1
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % cat in1
string newstring string
% <<<"$(<in2)" awk '{if(/oldstring/){x=sub(/oldstring/, "newstring", $0)};print}END{if(x!=1){print "newstring"}}' >in2
% cat in2
string foo string
newstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the right answer, because above proposal is illegat for multimple calls of script. For example you have file text1:

```
echo "1aaab" > text1
```

and script:

```
grep -q 1aaab text1&& 
    sed -i 's/1aaab/aaab/' text1|| echo "aaab" >> text1
```

on first call you'll got:

```
aaab
```

on second:

```
aaab
aaab
```

---

---

**The correct script is below:**

```
_conf=/etc/sysctl.conf                # our file
_commented=#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1     # searched insufficient text
_uncommented=net.ipv4.ip_forward=1    # text to reaplace insufficient or absent text

grep -q $_commented $_conf && (sed -i 's/'$_commented'/'$_uncommented/ $_conf || echo $_uncommented >> $_conf)
```

---

- if **net.ipv4.ip_forward=1** is absent - will be added new record **net.ipv4.ip_forward=1**
- if exists (commented by #) - will be uncommented from **#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1** to **net.ipv4.ip_forward=1**
- and **will be not spawn** multiple copies of expected text (net.ipv4.ip_forward=1) on each script call

Comment: 1) I think you're missing a few `$` in your code (`_commented` instead of `$_commented`?) 2) Even if we did add the `$`, variable expansion doesn't take place in single quotes 3) Even if we did switch to double quotes, your code will fail to add `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` if the file didn't contain `#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in the first place.