# replace uuid in a grub.cfg with sed

Tags: bash, 22.04, sed

How can I replace a UUID in a /boot/grub/grub.cfg with sed?

For some reason I have to replace string `88411b09-1aaa-4775-9fc7-f60041049d6c` with `f210c829-2c04-4963-9a78-d61cf8ebbd48` in a `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167500/add-new-uuid-to-each-line-of-a-file-using-sed-or-equivalent-command) but I'm unable to adapt it to my situation.
And I found [also this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700715/replace-or-add-a-string-to-a-file) but I get an error.

```
grep -q 88411b09-1aaa-4775-9fc7-f60041049d6c /media/alex/f210c829-2c04-4963-9a78-d61cf8ebbd48/boot/grub/grub.cfg && sudo sed -i 's/88411b09-1aaa-4775-9fc7-f60041049d6c/f210c829-2c04-4963-9a78-d61cf8ebbd48' /media/alex/f210c829-2c04-4963-9a78-d61cf8ebbd48/boot/grub/grub.cfg
sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: You should never edit grub.cfg, but either grub's scripts or its configuration file /etc/default/grub. But you would not normally have an external drive like /media/alex in grub. And then run `sudo update-grub`. Are you sure entry is not in fstab? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a slash at the end of the `'s/old/new/'` expression.

```
sudo sed -i 's/88411b09-1aaa-4775-9fc7-f60041049d6c/f210c829-2c04-4963-9a78-d61cf8ebbd48/' /media/alex/f210c829-2c04-4963-9a78-d61cf8ebbd48/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```